# Include non-android project in android project (lib or classpath)

Tags: java, android, ant, classpath

I'm trying to import a non-android project into my android-project in eclipse. I've tried everything, but nothing works.

I've added the project into my classpath -> noclassdeffounderror
I've created a .jar from my non-android project and moved it into "libs" -> same error
I've tried to "import an external jar" -> same error

I've searched the whole internet for getting this done, but I don't know, why I'm still getting this Exception by runtime.

Hope anyone has a good idea :(

Comment: Copying the jar file to the project libs folder is the correct thing to do. If that's not working...

Comment: I've done that... :( It still doesn't work.... , it is an "Ant" Project, maybe there is the error? I've nothing configured in the Ant-Files, but when I'm just debugging via eclipse and my cellphone I don't think that Ant has anything to do with it..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go into the project's <kbd>Properties</kbd>, select <kbd>Java Build Path</kbd>, select the <kbd>Order and Export</kbd> tab, and check the box next to the `JAR` file you're including.

Comment: It's checked, and it's "above" all of the other components  :/

Comment: @user1484047 Weird. Are you on ADT 21? Also, have you cleaned/rebuilt the project?

Comment: I've updated to adt21 and still can't get it running... is it possible that i have to configure my build.xml ? But i just debug via eclipse by pressing the debug button :/ beautiful Nicholas